# @media print { page-break-before; page-break-after} property not working in IONIC (angular)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, printing, page-break, page-break-inside

Suppose it's a sample code

```
<div id="print-div">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet page 1.</p>
     <ion-label>page break here</ion-label>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet page 2.</p>
</div>
```

I want to print this section, where first paragraph will be in 1st page and 2nd paragraph will be in next page.

#### in .ts file

```
printThis(){
   let backup = document.body.innerHTML;
   let divcontent = document.getElementById('print-div').innerHTML;
   document.body.innerHTML = divcontent;
   window.print();
   document.body.innerHTML = backup;
}
```

#### and in css

```
@media print {
    ion-label{
        page-break-before: always !important;
    }
}
```

But this does not breaking the page while printing.
All the data are printing in one page & if the content is larger than one page, it still printing ony one page's data.

I have tried with

```
page-break-before: always;
```

```
page-break-after: always;
```

```
break-after: always;
```

But nothing happening.

If anyone helps me a little bit that how to use the *page-break* property in ionic.
I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

The ion-content component has an inner div with absolute positioning. As ionic is using web-components with shadow-root and the positioning is not exposed as a css-variable, this style property cannot be set with the css stylesheet. But: Page-breaks don't work on absolute positioned elements [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp)

**Solution:**

Use JS to manipulate the shadow-root and set the positioning to relative. [github: ionic-print-test](https://github.com/btsiders/ionic-print-test)

I had the same problem and solved it by using the event-listeners `onbeforeprint` and `onafterprint`. Here is an example for ionic with angular but the logic can easily be refactored to react or vue. [ionic-print-test:issue](https://github.com/btsiders/ionic-print-test/issues/7)

**print.service.ts**

```js
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PrintService {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: HTMLDocument) {}

  init() {
    window.onbeforeprint = () => this.setPrintStyles(true);
    window.onafterprint = () => this.setPrintStyles(false);
  }

  private setPrintStyles(add: boolean) {
    this.document.querySelectorAll('ion-content').forEach((element) => {
      const scroll = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('.inner-scroll') as HTMLElement;
      if (add) {
        scroll.style.position = 'relative';
      } else {
        scroll.style.removeProperty('position');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir, I have tried this method but same issue. Maybe I am doing some mistake. Would you please tell me, how/where do you are calling the window.print() . In my case I have placed it either at the first line in init() or at the the last line of init()

Comment: Hi Sounak, just import the PrintService in your AppModule, add it to the constructor of your app.component.ts and call init() in your app.component. Afterwards the EventListeners are registered and you should be able to call window.print() in any other Component.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding this work. Ionic 4, Angular 8

```
@media print {
    body {
      position: relative !important;
    }
}
```

https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/angular-print-service-290651c721f9